# Compound and Complex Sentence Tokenization

Tags: nlp, transformer, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to tokenize sentences of a document for aspect-based sentiment analysis. There are some sentences that consist of more than one topic. For example, " The touch screen is good but the battery is weak" or " Their smartphones are great and their TVs are perfect". I want to tokenize sentences based on these conjunctions. Is there any pre-trained model for this task? Are there any other solutions? Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just use a typical tokenizer (e.g. sentencepiece or BPE). And, use a multi-label classification head on top of you model (i.e. sentence encoder) for the task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).